# error C2248: 'CvSVM::CvSVM' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CvSVM'

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, svm

I am trying to use bag of features model and train and SVM. I am using [this](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2011/08/25/a-simple-object-classifier-with-bag-of-words-using-opencv-2-3-w-code/) tutorial and [this](https://github.com/royshil/FoodcamClassifier) sample code. I am using Windows 8 and OpenCV 2.4.10. I am running this on Visual Studio 2012. But i am continuously getting this error 'CvSVM::CvSVM' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CvSVM' I tried using OpenCV 2.4.9 but same error is still there.

I searched a lot for this and still could not find a proper solution for this. Please help me on this. Thanks in advance. Below is the code. I am using this Dirent API for Microsoft Visual Studio as well.

EDIT: This is complete output from visual studio when compiling. Line 146 gives the error.

```
------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\utility(138): error C2248: 'CvSVM::CvSVM' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CvSVM'
1>          D:\Program Files\opencv\build\include\opencv2/ml/ml.hpp(553) : see declaration of 'CvSVM::CvSVM'
1>          D:\Program Files\opencv\build\include\opencv2/ml/ml.hpp(452) : see declaration of 'CvSVM'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\map(198) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair<const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>&,CvSVM>(_Other1,_Other2 &&,void **)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,
1>              _Ty2=CvSVM,
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<char>,
1>              _Other1=const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &,
1>              _Other2=CvSVM
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\map(198) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair<const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>&,CvSVM>(_Other1,_Other2 &&,void **)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,
1>              _Ty2=CvSVM,
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<char>,
1>              _Other1=const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &,
1>              _Other2=CvSVM
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\map(191) : while compiling class template member function 'CvSVM &std::map<_Kty,_Ty>::operator [](const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string,
1>              _Ty=CvSVM,
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          main.cpp(146) : see reference to function template instantiation 'CvSVM &std::map<_Kty,_Ty>::operator [](const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string,
1>              _Ty=CvSVM,
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          main.cpp(123) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string,
1>              _Ty=CvSVM
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

#include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <dirent.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>

    #include <opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp>

    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;

    int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
        string dir = "C:\\Users\\Rajind\\Downloads\\FoodcamClassifier-master\\FoodcamClassifier-master\\foodcamimages\\TRAIN", filepath;
        DIR *dp;
        struct dirent *dirp;
        struct stat filestat;

    dp = opendir( dir.c_str() );

    // detecting keypoints
    SurfFeatureDetector detector(1000);
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints; 

    // computing descriptors
    Ptr<DescriptorExtractor > extractor(new SurfDescriptorExtractor());//  extractor;
    Mat descriptors;
    Mat training_descriptors(1,extractor->descriptorSize(),extractor->descriptorType());
    Mat img;

    cout << "------- build vocabulary ---------\n";

    cout << "extract descriptors.."<<endl;

    int count = 0;
    while (count++ < 15 && (dirp = readdir( dp )))
    {
        filepath = dir + "/" + dirp->d_name;

        // If the file is a directory (or is in some way invalid) we'll skip it 
        if (stat( filepath.c_str(), &filestat )) continue;
        if (S_ISDIR( filestat.st_mode ))         continue;

        img = imread(filepath);
        detector.detect(img, keypoints);
        extractor->compute(img, keypoints, descriptors);

        training_descriptors.push_back(descriptors);
        cout << ".";
    }
    cout << endl;
    closedir( dp );

    cout << "Total descriptors: " << training_descriptors.rows << endl;

    BOWKMeansTrainer bowtrainer(150); //num clusters
    bowtrainer.add(training_descriptors);
    cout << "cluster BOW features" << endl;
    Mat vocabulary = bowtrainer.cluster();

    Ptr<DescriptorMatcher > matcher(new BFMatcher(NORM_L2,false));
    BOWImgDescriptorExtractor bowide(extractor,matcher);
    bowide.setVocabulary(vocabulary);

    //setup training data for classifiers
    map<string,Mat> classes_training_data; classes_training_data.clear();

    cout << "------- train SVMs ---------\n";

    Mat response_hist;
    cout << "look in train data"<<endl;
    count = 0;
    char buf[255];

    ifstream ifs("training.txt");
    int total_samples = 0;

    do
    {
        ifs.getline(buf, 255);
        string line(buf);
        istringstream iss(line);
//      cout << line << endl;
        iss >> filepath;
        Rect r; char delim;
        iss >> r.x >> delim;
        iss >> r.y >> delim;
        iss >> r.width >> delim;
        iss >> r.height;
//      cout << r.x << "," << r.y << endl;
        string class_;
        iss >> class_;

        img = imread(filepath);
        r &= Rect(0,0,img.cols,img.rows);

        if(r.width != 0) {
            img = img(r); //crop to interesting region
        }

        char c__[] = {(char)atoi(class_.c_str()),'\0'};
        string c_(c__);
        cout << ".";
//      putText(img, c_, Point(20,20), CV_FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2.0, Scalar(255), 2);
//      imshow("pic",img);
        bowide.compute(img, keypoints, response_hist);

        if(classes_training_data.count(c_) == 0) { //not yet created...
            classes_training_data[c_].create(0,response_hist.cols,response_hist.type());
        }
        classes_training_data[c_].push_back(response_hist);
        total_samples++;
//      waitKey(0);
    } while (!ifs.eof());
    cout << endl;

    //train 1-vs-all SVMs
    map<string,CvSVM> classes_classifiers;
    for (map<string,Mat>::iterator it = classes_training_data.begin(); it != classes_training_data.end(); ++it) {
        string class_ = (*it).first;
        cout << "training class: " << class_ << ".." << endl;

        Mat samples(0,response_hist.cols,response_hist.type());
        Mat labels(0,1,CV_32FC1);

        //copy class samples and label
        samples.push_back(classes_training_data[class_]);
        Mat class_label = Mat::ones(classes_training_data[class_].rows, 1, CV_32FC1);
        labels.push_back(class_label);

        //copy rest samples and label
        for (map<string,Mat>::iterator it1 = classes_training_data.begin(); it1 != classes_training_data.end(); ++it1) {
            string not_class_ = (*it1).first;
            if(not_class_[0] == class_[0]) continue;
            samples.push_back(classes_training_data[not_class_]);
            class_label = Mat::zeros(classes_training_data[not_class_].rows, 1, CV_32FC1);
            labels.push_back(class_label);
        }

        Mat samples_32f; samples.convertTo(samples_32f, CV_32F);
        classes_classifiers[class_].train(samples_32f,labels);
    }


    cout << "------- test ---------\n";

    //evaluate
    dir = "/Users/royshilkrot/Downloads/foodcamimages/TEST";
    dp = opendir( dir.c_str() );
    count = 0;
    while (count++ < 5 && (dirp = readdir( dp )))
    {
        filepath = dir + "/" + dirp->d_name;

        // If the file is a directory (or is in some way invalid) we'll skip it 
        if (stat( filepath.c_str(), &filestat )) continue;
        if (S_ISDIR( filestat.st_mode ))         continue;
        if (dirp->d_name[0] == '.')                  continue; //hidden file!

        cout << "eval file " << filepath << endl;

        img = imread(filepath);
        bowide.compute(img, keypoints, response_hist);

        //test vs. SVMs
        for (map<string,CvSVM>::iterator it = classes_classifiers.begin(); it != classes_classifiers.end(); ++it) {
            float res = (*it).second.predict(response_hist,false);
            cout << "class: " << (*it).first << ", response: " << res << endl;
        }

//      cout << ".";
    }
    cout << endl;
    closedir( dp );

    cout <<"done"<<endl;        
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is given because you can't access the copy constructor and copy assignment operator for CvSVM. That would require copying CvSVM objects which don't have public copy constructors. 
Just take a look at the definition of CvSVM:

```
// SVM model
class CV_EXPORTS_W CvSVM : public CvStatModel
{
public:

...

private:
    CvSVM(const CvSVM&);
    CvSVM& operator = (const CvSVM&);
};
```

You should try to use pointers instead - if you insist on using of containers of CvSVMs:

```
std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<CvSVM>>
```